# Navigate onclick from screen 1 to screen 2 and run specific component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-native

In my react-native project I want to onclick navigate from screen 1 to screen 2 but on screen 2 I want to only run specific component in screen 2 when the button is triggered in  screen 1

Comment: Please add more information to your question and add your codebases into this. Add your screen 1 and 2 codebases

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Is this not what routes are for?

Comment: I think he only needs to run specific function or component of screen 2 when click the button and not to navigate screen 2 . We need to check codebase

Comment: lack of details, please provide your source code and explain your issue